# Compressed JSON Content Type

Tags: json, http

I'm integrating a 3rd party API, and at one step they post JSON data into our server.

The content type they are sending is `application/json`, but the payload is actually gzipped, is this valid? I believe it should be `gzip/json` content type.

**Update 1**

the `env["RAW_POST_DATA"]` contains binary data, rather than JSON in text format that I would expect.

**Update 2**

This is a fairly standard Rails application, hosted on heroku with Puma for staging and production.

**Update 3**

I've not debugged at this level on heroku previously, <strike>so it's possible that I'm missing something, but I do not see a content-encoding header</strike> (I did miss the `"HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING"=>"gzip"` header). The headers that I do get are:

```
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001620+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001590 #7] DEBUG -- : REQUEST_PATH: /
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001660+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001620 #7] DEBUG -- : REQUEST_URI: /
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001701+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001656 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_VERSION: HTTP/1.1
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001735+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001698 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_HOST: staging.redacted.com
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001768+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001732 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_CONNECTION: close
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001801+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001765 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_ACCEPT:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001823+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001798 #7] DEBUG -- : CONTENT_LENGTH: 277
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001861+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001826 #7] DEBUG -- : CONTENT_TYPE: application/json
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001918+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001858 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001920+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001891 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_ORIGIN:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001958+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001921 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_USER_AGENT: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001996+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001953 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002029+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001992 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_DNT:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.001801+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.001765 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING: gzip
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002074+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.002027 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002093+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.002061 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002137+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.002094 #7] DEBUG -- : HTTP_COOKIE:
```

And the raw post data prints out as:

```
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002165+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2015-12-04T08:00:08.002128 #7] DEBUG -- : RAW_POST_DATA:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002166+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002168+00:00 app[web.1]: ���_%���R�@�S%@�4ݶ��n���wg�4$Wz��9�/me�J���pоp     Eٍ��!B�,N��@��k4g�
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002169+00:00 app[web.1]: -���*c�8�[�PK&DفR���LM�
2015-12-04T08:00:08.002169+00:00 app[web.1]: k=t@:?"'��Ip|�dpg��縼Ѻ|�u�cBC��Hly��*�ǯ'Meq�W�]N͛C�F
```

Comment: All content types may get encoded on transport level. If so that should be specified in the transport encoding header, not in the mime type. If that is not the case, then yes, that would be a violation of the specification.

Comment: My understanding is transport level compression is transparent to the application, but I am seeing binary data come into my application.

Comment: I'd say that depends on the environment your application runs in. If that takes care of the transport layer, then yes, it should be transparent for the application, _unless_ you specifically work with the raw data. If your environment does _not_ take care of the transport layer, then things look different. You did not specify any details about your environment or application.

Comment: Good point, I've update above

Comment: So what headers are specified? I'd say take a look, you have to anyway if you want to discuss that issue with that 3rdparty.

Comment: I believe your first comment has answered my question. It's now a matter of determining if they are truly sending it gzipped at the application level, which is not something that can be answered here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the request body is gzipped, and the request carries "Content-Encoding: gzip". No surprises here. See [RFC 7231 Section 3.1.2 Encoding for Compression or Integrity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2).

Comment: Yes, arkascha's comments pointed me in the right direction, It looks like the 3rd party is doing the right thing, but Rails is not. I've resolved the issue by adding a decompression step in the middleware.